# CodIgniter : css avaliable only on views called by the index function

Tags: php, codeigniter, web

My css file is only available on views called by the index function but other functions i get a 404 error that the css file cannot be found .
Here is my controller

```
class Enumurator extends CI_Controller {     

 public $layout_view = 'layouts/default';



 public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('enumurators_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index()
{ 
   $this->load->library('layout');         
   $this->layout->title('Enumurators'); 
   $data['enumurators'] = $this->enumurators_model->get_enumurators();
   $this->layout->view('enumurators', $data);     

}

public function addenumurator()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');    
$this->load->library('layout');        

$data['title'] = 'Create Enumurator';

$this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Telephone', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');


if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
{

    $this->load->view('newenumurator');


}
```

with

this :  "localhost/mis/enumurator "   it works fine

but

this :   "localhost/mis/enumurator/addenumurator "    the css cannot be found

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your CSS is linked in your `<head>` tag as relative I'm guessing, try it with an absolute path

Comment: can you post the css html <link...

Comment: check your <base> tag(if you have one) or add a slash to css path, so it could be accessed like `/site_css/your_css.css`(or whatever path you have)

Comment: load your css using src="<?=site_url('path_to_css');?>" as the src

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is likely to be related to how your stylesheet is linked in your HTML, not with your controller in CI.

At the moment, it's probably a relative path, like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some/path/to/css.css" />
```

This means when your URL is directly to your index, this path translates correctly to the path of the CSS. Once you add another directory (an additional `/something/`) to your URL the path now is incorrect.

To fix this, change the path to an absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yourdomain.com/some/path/to/css.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably using relative paths when linking assets, always use this approach to avoid relative path issues when using clean urls

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('css/file.css')?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('js/file.js')?>" />
```

or if you don't have short tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/file.css')?>" />
```

PS : don't forget to set your $config['base_url'] in /application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mis/';
```

that way, when you move your code to the production server, all you'll have to do is change this config variable.

Answer (score 0):

You must install codeigniter in your localhost as well as live server